# 404.php page template loads redirect to page with slug 404 - wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Currently when any page not found in my wordpress site the url is not changing only 404 page template loads, I want to change url like http://www.example.com/404 when any page not found.

somebody can help me? BTW Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is open your 404.php file in your theme’s folder. If it doesn’t exist, then create a blank php file. Paste the following code in there:

```
<?php
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
header("Location: ".home_url( '/404/' ));
exit();
?>
```

**OR**

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'unlisted_jobs_redirect' );
function unlisted_jobs_redirect()
{
    // check if is a 404 error, and it's on your jobs custom post type
    if( is_404())
    {
        // then redirect to yourdomain.com/jobs/
        wp_redirect( home_url( '/404/' ) );
        exit();
    }
}
```

Hope this will helps you. For more details please visit,

[wordpress 404 page redirect](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-redirect-your-404-page-to-the-home-page-in-wordpress/)

[Redirect Restricted Page to 404](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/24891/redirect-restricted-page-to-404)

Comment: The above code redirect me to domain url with 404 but i am having error that page isn't redirecting properly, maybe just because it can't find the 404.php file??

Comment: <?php
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
header("Location: ".home_url( '/404/' ));
exit();
?>

Answer (score 0):

Open your theme's 404.php page and add following code. If 404.php is not exist in your theme then create this file and add below code.

```
   header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
```

`$errorpage=get_permalink(PAGEID);  // PAGEID= 404 PAGE ID`

OR

`$errorpage=home_url( '/404/' );`

```
   header("Location: ".$errorpage);
   exit();
```

Comment: It triggers following error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '404' (T_LNUMBER), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) or '$'

Comment: oops sorry variable issue now check i have corrected

Comment: ok now url redirection is happening but my 404 template is not being load, how would i load 404 template on this url?

Comment: i have added your code in 404.php then after redirection should i have to create another file with template code?

Comment: You can add your content within that page as well

Comment: Not working , also created wordpress page with name 404 but that was also not loading template

Comment: share me the code which you did have you used that page id $errorpage=get_permalink(PAGEID);   here?

Comment: header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
$errorpage=get_permalink(PAGEID);
header("Location: ".$errorpage);exit();

Comment: You need to do some basic search page id means your newly created page id which is static for you like 2,3 or anything.

Comment: ok i tried with page id that displays my newly created page but my theme's 404.php file code is not working in that page